# Java JSON ignore null values when child objects are null but not the parent object

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, jackson2

I would like to create json file from below Object graph. Json file should exclude `NUll` and `Empty` value.
We do not want to print the name of the parent class when all of its property objects are null. 
please the code below.Any solution to remove/ignore writing these values?

---

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class A {
    @JsonProperty("classA.empName")
    public  B empName = new B();
    @JsonProperty("classA.emp_name")
    public  int age = 25;


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class B {
    @JsonProperty("classB.dept")
    public C dept = new C();
    @JsonProperty("classB.salary")
    public  Integer salary=5445455;
}


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class C {
    @JsonProperty("x")
    public  Integer x = null;
    @JsonProperty("y")
    public  Y y = null;
    @JsonProperty("z")
    public   Z z = null;

}
public class ToJSON {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static void main(String Args[]) throws IOException {
        A a = new A() ;
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(sourceObj));
    }
```

### }

output  : {"classA.empName":{"classB.dept":{},"classB.salary":5445455},"classA.emp_name":25}

expected: {"classA.empName":{"classB.salary":5445455},"classA.emp_name":25}

Comment: This code has not much information about what you are trying to do. Can you provide the code with all the annotations, fields, getter and setters?

Comment: I have updated query with code